# How do I use JS regex to capture a specific JSON value after its key?

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I have JSON data in the following format:

```
{"User":"aa2","Owner":"aa2_role","Status":"locked","Port":"5432","Description":"Transferred from CFS01 on Jun29","Project":"aa2","Server":"localhost"}
```

I can count on the **key** called **"Project":** to always be the same.

What I need is to pull the **Value** of the *"Project":* **key** which in this case is **"aa2"** using regex in JavaScript.

I have been trying different variations of /^("Project":)$/g but it is not working.

My last attempt I tried /[^"Project":$]/g but it gives me everything in the JSON Object but **"Project":**

Does anyone know how I can capture the value of a specific Project key?

**EDIT:** Just for clarification I agree with the use of the Parsing mechanism. My problem is that I am debugging/working with a previous code base that is using a separate function to pass the parsed JSON as a string into the function where now I need to pull the data needed from the string. After having spent this amount of time trying to come up with a work around I am about to scrap the function in order to use Parse... that's why I'm trying to use regex but the more I think about it, the more I realize that it's just bad code... but still, now I am just curious.

Comment: Why not use `JSON.parse` to parse the JSON properly?

Comment: `^` at the beginning of a *character group* (`[...]`) means *match everything **except** any of the following characters*.

Comment: *"What I need is to pull the Value of the "Project": key  .... using regex"* Why do you need to use a regular expression?

Comment: JSON stands for "JavaScript Object Notation", so obviously javascript has it's ways to handle those without resorting to regex.  But if you're curious about the regex, it would be more like `/"(?:Project)":"(\w*)"/g`. You could try it out in an online regex tester like for example [this one](http://regexr.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the JSON and then get the value. 
Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/vineeshmp/2c8z7r6u/

```
var json =' {"User":"aa2","Owner":"aa2_role","Status":"locked","Port":"5432","Description":"Transferred from CFS01 on Jun29","Project":"aa2","Server":"localhost"}';    
json = JSON.parse(json);
alert(json.Project);
```

Comment: sorry guys still not working im getting undefined....

Comment: See the fiddle for example, replace your json and see what is the issue

Answer (score 2):

No need to use Regular expression to extract value from object string. Just Use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). This will convert string to Object. After parsing you can use key to access the value.

```js
var obj = JSON.parse('{"User":"aa2","Owner":"aa2_role","Status":"locked","Port":"5432","Description":"Transferred from CFS01 on Jun29","Project":"aa2","Server":"localhost"}');

console.log(obj.Project);
```

Comment: sorry it doesnt work even when i parse it, i get the same undefined

Comment: @nasaQuant how did you try?

Comment: Dinesh I tried with the code you pasted. The issue was that I had to move the getElementById inside of the ajax Success call since it gets updated dynamically the value gets lost when not inside of the ajax success call. ugh.